# sum every 5 rows in one row in sql

Tags: sql, sum

I am new to sql Database.i have a problem

my table is like this

```
s.no |name  | amount
---------------------
1  | xyz    |   15
2  | xyz    |   54
3  | xyz    |  787
4  | xyz    |  455
5  | hhh    |   58
6  | hhh    |  789
7  | hhh    |  478
8  | hhh    | 7855
```

and I want result like this .

```
id |name|   | amount
---------------------
1  | xyz    |   15
2  | xyz    |   54
3  | xyz    |  787
4  | xyz    |  455
   | total  | 1311
5  | hhh    |   58
6  | hhh    |  789
7  | hhh    |  478
8  | hhh    | 7855
    total   | 9180
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to sum with an SQL query or with some programming language? Show some effort with what you have tried and exactly what is not working as expected.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the `rollup` clause, which is supported by many databases.

Here is what the query would look like in MySQL:

```
select s.no, name, sum(amount)
from mytable
group by name, s.no with rollup
```

You can do something like `coalesce(s.no, 'total')` to see the string total instead of a `NULL`.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, can i use rollup in mysql query?

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda . . . Yes:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
 select id,name,amount,grp from (

 select id,name,amount,name as grp from table1
 union ll
 select 0 as id,'Total' as name,sum(amount) as amount,
 concat(name,'-Total') as grp
 from table1 group by name ) as tab1 order by grp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the total every 5 rows you can run the next code below:

```
SELECT ceil(rownum/5) as "Group", sum(amount) as "sum_Efive"
FROM s.no
group by ceil(rownum/5);
```